# how to get html select box option selecteditem real value

Tags: jquery-selectbox

I'm getting DB data from the select box list.
When saving, the option value is 1, but is there a way to pass the id of the selected item as well?
When saving, yes or no is 0 or 1, but the id of the actually selected itemList should be stored in another table.

```js
$("#racker_enabled").change(function(){
   var selected_id = $("#tracker_enabled option:selected").val();      // option value 1만 찍힘..

});
```

```html
<select name="tracker_enabled" id="tracker_enabled">

<option th:value="0"  th:text="#{projects.Notused}"> </option>

<option  th:value="1"  th:if="${project.tracker_enabled == T(com.Type.EnumYn).Y}" 

             th:each="issuetrackerList:${issuetrackerList}"

            th:utext="${issuetrackerList.name}"

            th:selected="${issuetrackerList.id == selectedIssuetracker.issue_tracker_id}">

</option>

</select>
```

// Data contained in the model
// I need the id value in bold below. 
trackerList :

[IssueTracker (**id=13**, tracker_id=null, name=mantis, tracker_name=null, type=null, configuraion=null),

IssueTracker(**id=14**, tracker_id=null, name=mantis113,tracker_name=null, type=null, configuraion=null),

IssueTracker(**id=11**, tracker_id=null, name=Test IssueTracker, tracker_name=null, type=null, configuraion=null),

IssueTracker(**id=15**, tracker_id=null, name=gggg, tracker_name=null, type=null, configuraion=null)]

selectedTracker :

IssueTracker(id=200, issue_tracker_id=11, name=1111, issue_tracker_name=Test Tracker, type=1, configuraion=null)